# Uploading file to GCS bucket is giving error billing not enabled though Google support confirmed that billing is enabled

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload the image file to one of the bucket over GCS by using python google cloud storage api from the program. I am able to list out the buckets through the program but when uploading image, I am getting a below error. :

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/projbucket1/o?uploadType=multipart: {
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The account for bucket \"projbucket1\" has not enabled billing.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "The account for bucket \"projbucket1\" has not enabled billing.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "accountDisabled",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
}
]
}
}
: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

where projbucket1 is my bucket where I wanted to upload the file.

I am using below python code for that:

```
    def upload_image(Imagedata, kind):
        image_filename = Imagedata.filename
        fullpath = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/images', image_filename)
        bucket_name = "projbucket1"
        if kind == "User" :
            destination = "projbucket1/UserImages/"+image_filename
        else:
            destination = "projbucket1/PostImages/"+image_filename
    
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()
        for bucket in buckets:
            print(bucket.name)
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(destination)
        blob.upload_from_filename(fullpath)
```

I have **storage admin and owner** permissions for the service account I am using.  Please help me in this case.

Thanks,
Pranamya

Comment: Your Google Cloud account is disabled. Make sure your Google Payments account has a valid credit card. https://pay.google.com/

Comment: I am using other services like datastore which are working fine? I dont think it was disabled as I can still see my credit card associated with it. Can you tell me how to check if its disabled?

Comment: Figure out which project owns the bucket. Then look at the linked Billing Account. Then look at the linked Payments Account. Look at the error message in your question. It states: `"reason": "accountDisabled",`

Comment: I am not able to find out why this is giving me the account disabled error. No the billing is enabled for the project. I confirmed it from google customer support

Comment: You will need to go back to Google Cloud Billing Support with the error message.

Comment: Does the bucket you are using have the "[requester pays](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#check)" option enabled?